# struggling. trying to use bs4 and requests to extract latest news article but kept getting 'NoneType'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gI5g.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UcNn.png)

Been trying to simply extract online HTML URL from the website for a good day now. at this point not sure wtf I'm doing wrong. new to coding and never played with HTML before so I am clueless so what I had done wrong. thank you in advance.

trying to extract the latest news URL from a search tool in CNBC news.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_url = 'https://www.cnbc.com/search/?query=tesla&qsearchterm=tesla'

# Getting request from Shit
response = requests.get(search_url)
response.raise_for_status()

# HTML cooking
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the first news article link
article_link = soup.find('a', class_="resultlink")['href']

print("Latest news article URL:", article_link)
```

Comment: This is not an anything-goes general help forum: [do not show images of text](/help/how-to-ask), post _the text_ and then put it in [code markdown](/markdown) if it should be preformatted or even syntax highlighted.

Comment: Where did that html come from? If its from a browser, it could be that javascript filled in the data. Save response.text to a file and look at that. Is the element you want there?

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from different URL via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it). To get the titles you can simulate this query:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://api.queryly.com/cnbc/json.aspx"

params = {
    "queryly_key": "31a35d40a9a64ab3",
    "query": "tesla",  # <-- the query
    "endindex": "0",   # <-- increase this for additional pages (0, 10, 20, ...)
    "batchsize": "10",
    "callback": "",
    "showfaceted": "false",
    "timezoneoffset": "-120",
    "facetedfields": "formats",
    "facetedkey": "formats|",
    "facetedvalue": "!Press Release|",
    "needtoptickers": "1",
    "additionalindexes": "4cd6f71fbf22424d,937d600b0d0d4e23,3bfbe40caee7443e,626fdfcd96444f28",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
# print(data['results'])

for r in data['results']:
    print(r['cn:title'])
```

Prints:

```
Here are Monday's biggest analyst calls: Apple, Netflix, Amazon, Cava, Disney, Rivian, Tesla and more
EV sales: Hyundai overtakes GM, but Tesla's U.S. dominance continues
NHTSA presses Tesla for more records in Autopilot safety probe
Tesla still holds top spot in EV market with 60% share, Hyundai inches into second place
Tesla grows lead against EV competitors with 60% of sales in first half of 2023
EV 'truce' deal with Tesla and Chinese rivals is 'bad news' for Tesla, says former Ford CEO
Here's what analysts are saying after Tesla's second-quarter vehicle deliveries report
Tesla reported 466,140 deliveries for the second quarter, and production of 479,700 vehicles
These stocks, including Tesla, are this week's top performers as the S&P 500 falls
Tesla lacks the platform to justify its market valuation: Expert
```